# When to open your MySQL cursor

Tags: mysql, cursors

A relatively simple question but from all my research I have been unable to find a decent answer.

Which is technically more correct, open your cursor after your handlers have been defined or before you actually use your cursor?

For example,

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE a CHAR(16);
  DECLARE b, c INT;
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id,data FROM test.t1;
  DECLARE cur2 CURSOR FOR SELECT i FROM test.t2;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN cur1;
  OPEN cur2;

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO a, b;
    FETCH cur2 INTO c;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    IF b < c THEN
      INSERT INTO test.t3 VALUES (a,b);
    ELSE
      INSERT INTO test.t3 VALUES (a,c);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur1;
  CLOSE cur2;
END;
```

The above statements seem to be standard in most examples however would it be possible to do

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE a CHAR(16);
  DECLARE b, c INT;
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id,data FROM test.t1;
  DECLARE cur2 CURSOR FOR SELECT i FROM test.t2;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  SELECT x,y,z INTO @X, @Y, @Z FROM TableA WHERE X=1;

  IF (@X >= @Y) THEN

      OPEN cur1;
      OPEN cur2;

      read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur1 INTO a, b;
        FETCH cur2 INTO c;
        IF done THEN
          LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;
        IF b < c THEN
          INSERT INTO test.t3 VALUES (a,b);
        ELSE
          INSERT INTO test.t3 VALUES (a,c);
        END IF;
      END LOOP;

      CLOSE cur1;
      CLOSE cur2;
  ELSE 
      OPEN cur1;

      read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur1 INTO a, b;
        IF done THEN
          LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;
          INSERT INTO test.t3 VALUES (a,b);
      END LOOP;

      CLOSE cur1;
  END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see what your second code is doing. You want to open 2 cursors only if certain conditions are met, but only 1 cursor if not met. IMHO that should be fine.

In fact, the book [MySQL Stored Procedure Programming](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596100892) has this sample code on pages 110-111 under Example 5-17

```
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET l_last_customer=1;
SET l_last_customer=0;
OPEN customer_csr;
cust_loop:LOOP
    FETCH customer_crs INTO l_customer_id;
    IF l_last_customer=1 THEN LEAVE cust_loop; END IF;
    SET l_customer_count=l_customer_count+1;
    sales_block: BEGIN
        DECLARE l_last_sale INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET l_last_sale=1;
        OPEN sales_csr;
        sales_loop:LOOP
            FETCH sales_csr;
            IF l_last_sale=1 THEN LEAVE sales_look; END IF;
            CALL check_sale(l_sales_id);
            SET l_sales_count=l_sales_count+1
        END LOOP sales_loop;
    END sales_block;
END LOOP cust_loop;
SET l_last_customer=0;
CLOSE customer_csr;
```

Notice in the code the opening and closing of a cursor inside a `BEGIN...END` block. You should be OK with your code. If mysql complains, place your THEN code and ELSE code within `BEGIN...END` blocks.

Comment: Turns out that it only works if you use a begin and end block as you suggested.